# Python, calling a pandas series starting with number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with 124 columns, one of these columns is named '1ST', thus when I try to call it I get this error:

```
[IN]: print(data.1ST)
[OUT]:   File "<ipython-input-163-1807245f448a>", line 1
           print(data.1ST)
                ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to call this series? 
I've already tried with something like this:

```
[IN]: print(eval('data.' + str(1ST)))
```

but that still doesn't work

Comment: `print(data['1ST'])` ?

Answer (score 1):

use index notation

```
data['1ST']
```